# Wait for completion possible in user-space?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel, synchronization

There is a couple of functions I really like, when synchronizing threads in a Linux driver, which is : 
`wait_for_completion()` and its counterpart `complete_and_exit()`

Is it feasible to implement this api with 2 threads, sharing a memory map, respectively a writer in kernel and a reader in user-space ?

If not, what would be the effort to provide `wait_for_completion()` to the C language user-space thread ?

Regards, 
CyrIng
(Fr)

Comment: Sure, why not?  Is this functionality not normal?

Comment: +Martin: it is normal but limited to the Kernel, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

A user-space process can use `ioctl()` calls on a device file created via `mknod`.  Your device driver can use the arguments from the `ioctl` system call to come up with arguments to a `wait_for_completion()` call.  For example, a user process could use `ioctl()` to pass a structure containing a code of some kind to identify what it wants, a pointer to a user-space buffer, and a size field containing the size of the buffer.  The kernel thread processing the `ioctl()` could then block on `wait_for_complete()`, then fill in the user-space buffer with data.

See [this web page](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/08/io-control-in-linux/) for an example of `ioctl()` processing:

> **Introducing ioctl()**
>
> Input/Output Control (ioctl, in short) is a common operation, or
>   system call, available in most driver categories. It is a
>   one-bill-fits-all kind of system call. If there is no other system
>   call that meets a particular requirement, then ioctl() is the one to
>   use.
>
> Practical examples include volume control for an audio device, display
>   configuration for a video device, reading device registers, and so on
>   — basically, anything to do with device input/output, or
>   device-specific operations, yet versatile enough for any kind of
>   operation (for example, for debugging a driver by querying driver data
>   structures).
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks. Will try to mix ```ioctl``` with the shared memory where could be stored the completion variables.